# Getting error 404 when trying to access images by URL in Grails 2.3.7

Tags: grails

Currently, when trying to access an image through a url I am getting the Error 404 (Not Found).

URL example:

> http: // localhost:8084/prod/static/files/users/profile/photos/man-161282_640.png)

I'm create the images in a folder in webapps directory (webapps / files / users / profile / photos /). 
If I try access the folder through the System Operating System files, I saw that the file was created correctly with the correct permissions.